# Python Filtering lists? - Lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

what I have here is two lists one being:

```
c=["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "white", "black"]
```

and then I have the two following sequences that produce a list of fifty random colors:

```
nuSequence = map(lambda x : random.randint(0,7),range(50))
colSequence = map(lambda i: c[i], nuSequence)
print colSequence
```

Followed by this little function that stores the list of occurrences in order of the list 'c'.

```
count2 = map(lambda x: nuSequence.count(x),range(len(c)))
```

What I need to do is print out the name of the color followed by the number of times it occurred, like so : `blue - 7` or vice versa.

I am afraid to say you cannot use any imports or loops using only filter, and reduce or len

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: So what's the problem? What code do you have so far, and why do you think it isn't working?

Comment: I have tried 
count2 = map(lambda x: nuSequence.count(x),range(len(c)))
count = filter(lambda x: "{}{}".format(count2(x), c(x)), c)
print count

Comment: @Stooodent By the way, your tutor is clearly an idiot. Why... just why...?

Comment: One - It's learning to work with limitations. Two - Yeah he is, you don't have to tell me. and Three - This wouldn't be so bad if I had worked with python before but I've only ever worked with C# or Java :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am afraid to say you cannot use any imports or loops using only
>   filter, and reduce or len

mmkay.  I'll note that both `filter` and `reduce` (and `map`, and...) use loops, just tucked away in native code.

```
def update_agg(agg,x):
    agg[x] = agg.get(x,0)+1
    return agg

reduce(lambda agg,x: update_agg(agg,x), colSequence, {})
Out[130]: 
{'black': 4,
 'blue': 5,
 'green': 6,
 'orange': 5,
 'purple': 6,
 'red': 8,
 'white': 10,
 'yellow': 6}
```

Then format that `dict` however you'd like if that output isn't good enough for you.

*edit:* lambdas are just anonymous functions.  But if you *really* don't want that `def`, we can technically do that...

```
reduce(lambda agg,x: agg.__setitem__(x,agg.get(x,0)+1) or agg, colSequence, {})
```

Notice how lambda syntax really makes things near-unreadable.  Such is functional programming in python.

Comment: Sorry - but you got the gist of what I meant

Comment: Thanks man that works great but I'm really looking for a solution without any defining functions if that's possible

Comment: @Stooodent lambdas *are* defining functions.  That said, it's possible (not something I'd recommend, since it makes the thing way less readable), see edit.

Comment: Thanks man i'll give it a go now and let you know how it goes. Unfortunately its the purpose of the assignment, if it weren't the case I wouldn't be needed the help :/

Edit:@roippi Thanks man, worked great. I owe you aha

Answer (score 0):

```
print "yellow: %d" % len( filter( lambda x: x == "yellow", c ) )
```

Comment: Sorry I just updated the question. 
What I am really looking for is to iterate through the 'count2' map and the 'c' list to create the printed answer. 
So far I have tried: - 
count = filter(lambda x: "{}{}".format(count2(x), c(x)), c)     
print count - which hasn't worked yet